# How do you send a Google Map API route to Android Navigator?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I started a project for a class a few semesters ago but never finished it because I could not find out how to do it! I got a B for the class, but it has been bothering me.

I am able to take YOUR location and map a route to various pre-decided locations (football fields) on your android: http://www.billynair.com/school/dgm3790/final/ (sorry, does not work on desktop yet) using the Google Maps API. It will show you the route and you can zoom in and out, but I want it to send to your device's Navigation app. I have asked around, searched until my fingers bled, and still no answers a year later.

Is there a way to send this API generated route to Android's Navigation app?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. It should forward the coordinates you got to the default navigation app.

```
String tag = "google.navigation:q=" + the_latitude + "," + the_longitude;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(tag));
startActivity(intent);
```

However, this method appears to be totally unofficial and poorly documented.

Comment: are there any libraries I need to import for that? I have the maps API, jquery, gears_init.js, and geo.js. this line is killing it: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(tag));

Comment: I tried "import com.mylibrary.activities.ImportedActivity;" but I am guessing I need to include something else before that for it to work. I found that "android.content.Intent" looks like the class that I need, but I have no clue how to get it into my code... stuck in "package com.test.intent;" also. Maybe I am putting them in the wrong place?

Comment: This code is to be placed in your `Activity`, or if you're fetching the lat/lng value in a `AsyncTask`, in the `onPostExecute` method for example. If you have to start an activity outside of an `Activity`, you will have to use the `Context` as such : `context.startActivity(intent);`. The only package needed to do this  is `android.content.Intent`. After your package declaration line, you can just `import android.content.Intent;`